# Function returns nothing in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I created a function:

```
create or replace function get_columns
(v_table_name IN varchar2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
  v_columns_list VARCHAR2(2048);
BEGIN
  SELECT listagg(column_name,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name) AS t_list into v_columns_list
      FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE owner='MyOwner' AND table_name=v_table_name;
      RETURN v_columns_list;
END;
```

When I test this function it returns nothing to the output:

```
declare
v_columns_list varchar2(2048);
v_table_name varchar2(100) := 'MyTable';
begin
--  SELECT listagg(column_name,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name) AS t_list INTO v_columns_list
--      FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE owner='MyOwner' AND table_name=v_table_name;
  v_columns_list := get_columns(v_table_name);
  dbms_output.put_line(v_columns_list);
end;
```

Result:

```
anonymous block completed
```

However when I test the same "SELECT INTO" statement it works fine and returns concatenated string:

```
declare
v_columns_list varchar2(2048);
v_table_name varchar2(100) := 'MyTable';
begin
  SELECT listagg(column_name,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name) AS t_list INTO v_columns_list
      FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE owner='MyOwner' AND table_name=v_table_name;
--  v_columns_list := get_columns(v_table_name);
  dbms_output.put_line(v_columns_list);
end;
```

Why can that be?

Comment: why are you recursively calling the same function once you have the result?

Comment: works fine for me.  You sure dbms_output was enabled?

Comment: you have `owner = 'MyOwner'` and `v_table_name varchar2(100) := 'MyTable';`. I presume those are example names you have given; in your real case, are they in upper case? If not, try making them upper case.

Comment: @Boneist Yes, these are example names, and the real names were uppercase.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Yes, I am sure that dbms_output was enabled, because when I ran anonymous block with explicit SELECT INTO it resulted as concatenated column names, but when function was assigned to dbms_output.put_line argument variable, it has not resulted that way - nothing came to the output.

Comment: @kevinsky could you please describe more particularly what you mean?

Comment: @griboedev never mind, I was not reading your code correctly, sorry!

Comment: Assuming `MyUser' isn't the function owner, does the owner have permission on 'MyTable' granted directly, or through a role? Are you calling the function (and more importantly doing the direct select...into) as the same user you created the function as?

Comment: @AlexPoole The permission was granted directly. I am calling function and doing direct select into as the same user as one who created the function.

Comment: @griboedov - what you're seeing suggests it's through a role; can you query `select * from all_tab_privs where table_name = 'MyTable'` and see if it lists your user as a grantee, or just a role that it has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is querying the `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` view for tables owned by a specific user, which presumably is not the same schema as the function itself is in, and you can't see the table columns in that function. But you can see the table columns when you query `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` directly or in an anonymous block.

That means your schema has select permission on the table you're looking for granted via a role. Such permissions are not honoured inside a named PL/SQL block. You'd be able to see the same thing if you did `set role none` before running the `select ... into` version; the table would not appear in `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` for you as you would no longer have permission to query it.

You can make the function use [invoker's rights](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00809) instead of the default definer's rights:

```
create or replace function get_columns
(v_table_name IN varchar2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
AUTHID CURRENT_USER
AS
...
```

... but then you're relying on the caller having permission to see the table, either directly or through a role. Which might not be a bad thing - if the caller doesn't have permission to select from the table, maybe you don't want them to be able to see its structure either.

You could also grant permission on the table directly to the function owner, but you'd have to do that for every table you want others to be able to look at through the function, which might be painful and loses the advantages of the role.

It might be simpler to query `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS` instead, and get your DBA to give you the necessary privileges to be able to see that view if you can't already. You then won't be restricted to the tables you have direct select privileges against.